# Nlog - Adding a deepness data

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm currently working on a custom installer, and a lot of my company's softwares use a specific log format (and we have  a lot of tools to analyse them) but all of their programs are written in Delphi and the project i'm working on use C# so i can't reuse directly the library.

So i'm trying to format the NLog's output to fit our format while still having a "standard" output and being able to output the logs directly in a WPF control.

We have all the usual log level (debug, info, warning, error, ...) but we also have deepness mechanism. Basically we can have things like:

```
log.Info("Hey");
log.BeginBlock("Some logs");
for(....)
{
    instructions;
    log.Error("...");
}
log.EndBlock();
log.Info(".");
```

Basically the output will be:

```
Time Deepness Message Warning Error
[TIME] 1 Hey 0 0
[TIME] 1 Some logs 0 0
[TIME] 2 ... 0 1
[TIME] 1 . 0 0
```

So i'm wondering if I can do something like that with NLog or if i should consider another Log framework

thanks !

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is what you're after, so submitting as a comment instead as an answer: try taking a look at [the MDC layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Mdc-Layout-Renderer).

Comment: It looks like it can do what I want to. I'll give it a try tommorow :)

Comment: It worked ! Thanks :)

Comment: Okay then, I'll submit a basic answer along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Mapped Diagnostics Context layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Mdc-Layout-Renderer).  It lets you add contextual information that flows along with your code.  Very useful.

> Use the Mapped Diagnostics Context when you have information that you want available to every logger executing on the current thread. As the Mapped Diagnostics Context is thread-local, you must configure all properties within the context of each thread where the property value is required.

Example usage:

```
MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("PropertyName", "PropertyValue");
```

Then in the log config:

```
${mdc:item=PropertyName}
```

Comment: I would like to add this to the SO documentation, but I do need some votes: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/nlog/commit. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the nested  the [Nested Diagnostics Context layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ndc-Layout-Renderer) is a better choice, although is missing some good examples.

Example usage:

```
NestDiagnosticsContext.Push("entering method X");
...
NestDiagnosticsContext.Pop(); //leaving methods
```

Then in the log config:

```
${ndc}
```

See also the [NestedDiagnosticsContext class docs](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/T_NLog_NestedDiagnosticsContext.htm)